# How to run code after Scrapy has finished crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

How to run code after Scrapy has finished crawling

I have a spider:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class KpallSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['kupujemprodajem.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.kupujemprodajem.com/Usluge-Auto-moto/Automehanicar/1410-1426-1-grupa.htm']


    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['grupa.htm']),callback='parse_item',follow=True)]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        url = str(response.url)
        yield {'url':url}
```

I want to write to JSON

And after scrapy has finished crawl i want to:

```
print('Something')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, on your favorite shell:

```sh
scrapy crawl test -o items.json && echo "Something"
```

Or could do the same in your python like this:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
    'FEED_URI': 'items.json'
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished

print("Something")
```